# How to prove that gamma function is analytic (holomorphic) on the right half plane?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

Let 
$$
\Gamma(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{\lambda-1} dx.
$$
How can I prove that $\Gamma$ is an analytic function?

My attempt: we can let $f(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{\lambda-1} \ln x dx$. Expanding $e^t$ into a power series, we get the inequality
$$
|x^{\lambda-1}-x^{\lambda_0-1}|\leq x^{-\epsilon} |\lambda-\lambda_0||x^{\lambda_0-1}||\ln x|, x\leq 1, |\lambda-\lambda_0|<\epsilon.
$$
So, 
$$
|\Gamma (\lambda)-\Gamma(\lambda_0)-(\lambda-\lambda_0)f(\lambda_0)|=\left|\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(x^{\lambda-1}-x^{\lambda_0-1}-(\lambda-\lambda_0)x^{\lambda_0-1} \ln x)dx\right|.
$$
It seems that I am getting the correct inequality, but I don't know how to proceed. The inequality doesn't seem to fit nicely into this integral. The aim is something like
$$
|x^{\lambda-1}-x^{\lambda_0-1}-(\lambda-\lambda_0)x^{\lambda_0-1} \ln x|<\epsilon,
$$
although such uniform convergence is unlikely to be achieved.

Some more attempts:

$$
e^{(\lambda-\lambda_0)\ln x}=1+(\lambda-\lambda_0)\ln x+\frac12 (\lambda-\lambda_0)^2(\ln x)^2+\ldots\\
\Rightarrow x^{\lambda-1}-x^{\lambda_0-1}=x^{\lambda_0-1}(x^{\lambda-\lambda_0}-1)\\
=x^{\lambda_0-1}((\lambda-\lambda_0)\ln x+\frac12 (\lambda-\lambda_0)^2(\ln x)^2+\ldots)\\
\Rightarrow x^{\lambda-1}-x^{\lambda_0-1}-(\lambda-\lambda_0)x^{\lambda_0-1} \ln x=x^{\lambda_0-1}(\frac12 (\lambda-\lambda_0)^2(\ln x)^2+\ldots)
$$

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let$$\Gamma_n(\lambda)=\int_0^ne^{-x}x^{\lambda-1}\,\mathrm dx.$$Then $\Gamma_n$ is analytic. Besides, $(\Gamma_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $\Gamma$ on every compact subset of the right half-plane. Therefore, $\Gamma$ is analytic.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of the theorem you are using?

Comment: The theorem that I have used is Weierstrass' convergence theorem. See, for instance Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of complex functions*, chapter 8, section 4.

Comment: How to prove that $\Gamma_n$ is holomorphic?

Comment: @BokaPeer Because, for each $x\in[0,n]$, $\lambda\mapsto e^{-x}x^{\lambda-1}$ is analytic and because the map $(x,\lambda)\mapsto e^{-x}x^{\lambda-1}$ is continuous.